# usage of succeeded

Tags: grammaticality

Is usage of succeeded correct here?

> Windows 98 is used to be an popular software. Nevertheless, it is no 
>   longer maintained now, as it is **succeeded** by newer version of windows.

Comment: Your use of succeeded is correct; however, note a couple of other points: "Windows 98 <strike>is</strike> used to be **a** popular software. Nevertheless, it is no longer maintained <strike>now</strike>, as it **has been** succeeded by newer version**s** of **W**indows."

Answer (score 2):

If something succeeds something else, it means that something replaces or comes after something else. So the use of "succeeded"is correct in your statement.